# Dealing with missing values when writing logical expressions

Tags: r

If you are familiar with SAS you know that missing values are considered as `-inf`, therefore, for an expression like this:

```
If a < 2 then c=1 ; 

else c= 5;
```

Where "a" is missing; value of 1 will be assigned to c, because the logical expression "a < 2" will be "True". Please notice that my question is about the **outcome of the **logical expression****. I do not care about "c".

I would like to get the same thing in R but the result of the logical expression will be "NA" :

> a <-NA

> a < 2

```
[1] NA
```

How can I change the output of this logical expression to "True" ?

I know I can do this:

```
output < ifelse( is.na(a), False, a <2)
```

But I am looking for something simple. Any ideas?

Comment: NA means the variable's value in that observation is not known (it could be anything). If the value is not known, how could you expect a comparison to resolve to TRUE? Your ifelse function is probably the simplest way to handle it.

Comment: You are right, but I prefer to have "FALSE" for the missing ones rather than an NA, becuase I will be using the outcome of this expression in the next steps and giving NA as input just stops my algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

If you use this frequently enough, then you could define an infix operator to wrap around your `ifelse`:

```r
`%<%` <- function(a, b) { ifelse(is.na(a), TRUE, a < b) }
```

So if `a` is

```r
a <- c(NA, 1, 3, 5, NA)
```

Then you only need do:

```r
a %<% 2
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: This might give unexpected results for `a <- NA; b <- NA`....

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that `NA` is a logical object.

`(a < 2) | is.na(a)`

Comment: See [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, and I am absolutely **not** recommending this approach:

```r
Ops.sas <- function (e1, e2) {
  comparison <- switch(.Generic, `<` = , `>` = , `==` = , `!=` = ,
                    `<=` = , `>=` = TRUE, FALSE)
  if (comparison) {
    e1[is.na(e1)] <- -Inf
    e2[is.na(e2)] <- -Inf
  }
  
  NextMethod(.Generic)
}
```

And now:

```
> foo <- structure(c(NA, 2,3,2, NA), class = "sas")
> bar <- structure(c(2,3,2, NA, NA), class = "sas")
> foo < bar
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> foo <= bar
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> foo == bar
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> foo != bar
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> foo > bar
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> foo >= bar
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is.na(a) | a < 2){
   c=1
} else {
   c=2
}
```

I think that the simplest way is just to add a new condition in your test. In R the `|` symbol stands for OR.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will have to modify the values in `a` for example like this

```r
a <- c(NA, 1, 3, 4, NA)
a
#> [1] NA  1  3  4 NA

a < 2
#> [1]    NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA

a[is.na(a)] <- -Inf

a < 2
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>